# UINavigationController & SplitViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitviewdelegate

I have a project where I use a `NavigationController` as a detailed view for my `SplitViewController`.

So when the app shows up, everything is fine in both orientations. However as soon as i push a view inside my navigation controller, if i'm in portrait mode my button to 'show master view' (uisplitview delegate) will disapear and the 'back' button of the `uinavigationcontroller` will replace it. If i press the back button to pop my view, the 'show master view' button comes back.

My question is, how do i manage the fact that i want to be able to show both buttons ('back', 'show master') in my `UINavigationBar` even if i have pushed some views?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a UIToolbar. You must first hide the navigationbar and place a UiToolbar on the top of the view.

Now you can add as buttons as you want.

```
UIToolbar *tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 1036, 42)];          
tools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

UIBarButtonItem * backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myCustomView];
[buttons addObject:backButton];

//you can add also a spacer
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:spacer];

UIBarButtonItem * homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myCustomView];
[buttons addObject:homeButton];
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do that with a regular `UINavigationBar`.

You'd have to place your "show master view" button somewhere else - e.g. in a `UIToolbar` at the bottom of your detail view.

Or you could code your own NavigationController and NavigationBar, but that's a bit more work. :)